# PHP XML DOM Why cannot add new record into XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom

there. First time to touch XML thing. But my code cannot add new record into XML file. Please help me out.

First thing first, I have **studentdb.xml** like this:

```
<root></root>
```

And then, **insertxml.php** file is like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $xml = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml-> formatOutput = true;
    $xml->load('http://www.beautysalonishere.tk/studentdb.xml');

    $cname = $_POST['c_name'];
    $hadd = $_POST['h_add'];

    $rootTag = $xml->getElementByTagName("root")->item(0);

    $infoTag = $xml->createElement("info");

        $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name", $cname);
        $addTag = $xml->createElement("address", $hadd);

        $infoTag->appendChild($nameTag);
        $infoTag->appendChild($addTag);

    $rootTag->appendChild($infoTag);
    $xml->save('http://www.beautysalonishere.tk/studentdb.xml');
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<form method = "POST" action = "insertxml.php">
Stud Info</br>
PNAME<input type ="text" name="c_name"></br>
add <input type ="text" name="h_add"></br>
<input type="submit" name "insert" value="add">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where goes wrong that cause me cannot add new record.

Comment: Shouldn't `getElementByTagName` be `getElementsByTagName` (elements plural)? Sounds like you just need to enable `display_errors`. FYI, you can also get the root tag via [`$xml->documentElement`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documentelement)

Comment: Yup, works fine here using `$xml->documentElement` ~ https://eval.in/416052

Comment: @Phil Wait.. You sure it's working? I changed that line to: 【$rootTag = $xml->documentElement("root")->item(0);】 But still no change for the result. How?

Comment: Wha? Did you even look at my example? It's `$rootTag = $xml->documentElement;`

Comment: Make sure your `php.ini` file on your development server has `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. You have syntax errors and you're not seeing them at all

Comment: @Phil It's a free hosting. I don't think I have permission of that. Anyway, since the code is not long.. Did you inspect any syntax error? I checked it twice and I think it is okay...

Comment: You dev in your production environment? Ok, live fast, die young and all that. And yes, both `$xml->getElementByTagName('root')->item(0)` and `$xml->documentElement('root')->item(0)` are both syntax errors in that neither `getElementByTagName` nor `documentElement` are functions. Again, see the example in my second comment, ie **click this link** ~ https://eval.in/416052

Comment: Good site. Can't really fix it out. Now I'm suspect the server issue.

Comment: Could be you're also missing an `=` between `name` and `"insert"` in your submit button which means `$_POST['insert']` will never be set. You can also enable error reporting in your script; place this at the top just under the `<?php` tag ~ `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up from all the comments...

1. Fix your submit button's `name` attribute

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="insert" value="add">
   ```
2. Set `$rootTag` via

   ```
   $rootTag = $xml->documentElement;
   ```

Also, you won't be able to `save` the XML to that remote location. I'm assuming your host is actually *beautysalonishere.tk* and your scripts are in the document root, so use

```
$dbFile = __DIR__ . '/studentdb.xml';

$xml->load($dbFile);
```

and

```
$xml->save($dbFile);
```